# Is it safe to store a session ID with window.history.replaceState?

Tags: javascript

A little bit of context: for various reasons I am trying to avoid session cookies. The solution I came up with works as follows:

- Pass the session ID as an additional parameter with each link and form internal to the website. The corresponding parameters are inserted by the server. [PHP seems to support this type of URL-based session handling natively](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.use-trans-sid) - although I am not using PHP for my project, and it is easy enough to do. I am well aware of the effect that I then need to handle dynamically generated links etc. myself.
- A security concern with this approach is that users could paste a URL including the session ID into a forum or email, which allows others to hijack their session and hence their account. I'd address this with a small script that strips the session ID off the URL. The script uses `window.history.replaceState(sessionID, '', strippedURL)` to remove the ID from the URL, and at the same time stores the ID in the corresponding state for later use by Javascript, e.g., when the user opens the page again by means of navigating "back".

My question is: **Is the window history a safe place for a session ID when stored as a state?** Is it possible by any means for a script coming from a different domain (or even a different URL in the same domain) to obtain such an ID if the page containing that curious script is opened later in the same window? I am not talking about XSS, but about accessing the history later when the user has moved on. I expect the answer to be "no", but I'd like to know for sure and therefore get an expert opinion. Thanks!

Comment: "*for various reasons I am trying to avoid session cookies*". Such as?

Comment: Session hijacking will always be a risk. This means that using a cookie vs the `window` DOM poses the same level of risk. Since you are using a custom authentication method, it would be completely up to you to circumvent these unique risks. (This article covers cookies but session keys are the important takeaway from this)
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Periodic_Table_of_Vulnerabilities_-_Cookie_Theft/Session_Hijacking